# Не находит класс SocialiteProviders\Discord\DiscordExtendSocialite

Tags: php, laravel

В EventServiceProvider.php  я указал 'SocialiteProviders\Discord\DiscordExtendSocialite@handle', однако все равно получаю ошибку "Class SocialiteProviders\Discord\DiscordExtendSocialite does not exist". Причем до установки работала и авторизация через VK, STEAM, сейчас же перейдя на любую авторизацию - получаю эту ошибку. Мой мозг в замешательстве, надеюсь на вашу помощь :(

P.S использовал документацию - https://socialiteproviders.netlify.com/providers/discord.html

Comment: Ведущий \ забыли.

Comment: Да нет, если его поставлю, то ошибка превращается в "Class \SocialiteProviders\Discord\DiscordExtendSocialite does not exist"

При этом файлы для авторизации скачивал с github'a socialite https://github.com/SocialiteProviders/Discord

Comment: Как скачивали, напрямую, без Composer? Эта ссылка на Дискорд провайдер должна устанавливаться через него, вообще-то.

Comment: Да, просто взяв файлы и перенес на сервер, с другими провайдерами сделал, работало) Просто впервые такую делал, вот и туплю :/

Comment: Нет, ну сам socialite я ставил через composer require socialiteproviders/discord